# MySQL - length() vs char_length()

Tags: mysql, string

What's the main difference between `length()` and `char_length()`?

I believe it has something to do with binary and non-binary strings.  Is there any practical reason to store strings as binary?

```
mysql> select length('MySQL'), char_length('MySQL');
+-----------------+----------------------+
| length('MySQL') | char_length('MySQL') |
+-----------------+----------------------+
|               5 |                    5 |
+-----------------+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: Yes, there is practical reasons to store binary strings when they actually are binary strings, e.g. compressed.

Answer (score 375, accepted):

`LENGTH()` returns the length of the **string measured in bytes**.  
`CHAR_LENGTH()` returns the length of the **string measured in characters**.

This is especially relevant for Unicode, in which most characters are encoded in two bytes.  Or UTF-8, where the number of bytes varies.  For example:

```
select length(_utf8 '€'), char_length(_utf8 '€')
--> 3, 1
```

As you can see the Euro sign occupies 3 bytes (it's encoded as `0xE282AC` in UTF-8) even though it's only one character.

Comment: Only UCS-2 is encoded in two bytes per character. This encoding (or more accurately UTF-16LE) is what Windows misleadingly calls “Unicode”. MySQL doesn't support UTF-16; instead the usual approach for putting Unicode strings in it is to use UTF-8.

Comment: For example: select length('日本語'), char_length('日本語');

Comment: @bobince: Even UCS-2 encodes some characters in more than 2 bytes, for example `0313 combining comma above`.  Since a = 61, 0x00610313 displays as a̓, and it takes up 4 bytes.

Comment: Actually by Unicode terminology that's still 2 characters, even though like all combining marks it can — if a suitable font is available — be rendered as a single glyph. UTF-16LE can still have a 4-byte character though thanks to the surrogates.

Comment: So which of these functions should I use when figuring out how to resize my VARCHAR columns? When creating the table lets say one column is a VARCHAR(10). Will that allow a maximum of 10 characters, or a maximum of 10 bytes?

Comment: UCS-2 is NOT UTF-16LE.  UCS-2 is 2 bytes per character, but UTF-16LE is Little Endian and 2 or 4 bytes per character (surrogate pairs to represent characters >FFFF (2 surrogates = 1 character))

Answer (score 20):

varchar(10) will store 10 characters, which may be more than 10 bytes.
In indexes, it will allocate the maximium length of the field - so if you are using UTF8-mb4, it will allocate 40 bytes for the 10 character field.

Comment: How is this related to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Though here answer provided by @Andomar is correct, I am tempted to provide a more detailed answer.

**NAME IN ENGLISH** -

Suppose I create a variable `@name` storing my name -

```
SET @name = "Payel Senapati";
```

Now, I create a variable `total_characters` to store the number of characters my name occupy -

```
SET @total_characters =  CHAR_LENGTH(@name);
SELECT @total_characters;
+-------------------+
| @total_characters |
+-------------------+
|                14 |
+-------------------+
```

---

**Case 1:**

I create a variable `@test` to store `@name` converted to `latin1` character set -

```
SET @test = CONVERT(@name USING latin1);
```

I create a variable `@total_bytes` and store the length of `@test` in terms of bytes -

```
SET @total_bytes = LENGTH(@test);
SELECT @total_bytes;
+--------------+
| @total_bytes |
+--------------+
|           14 |
+--------------+
```

Now, `latin1` character set allocated 1 byte per character.

Thus, `@total_characters = @total_bytes`

---

**Case 2:**

Now, in variable `@test` I store `@name` converted to `ucs2` character set -

```
SET @test = CONVERT(@name USING ucs2);
```

Now, in variable `@total_bytes` I store the length of `@test` in terms of bytes -

```
SET @total_bytes = LENGTH(@test);
SELECT @total_bytes;
+--------------+
| @total_bytes |
+--------------+
|           28 |
+--------------+
```

Now, `ucs2` character set allocated 2 bytes per character.

Thus, `2 * @total_characters = @total_bytes`

---

**NAME IN HINDI** -

Now, I store my name in variable `@name` in Hindi -

```
SET @name = "पायल सेनापति";
```

Now, in variable `total_characters` I store the number of characters my name occupy in Hindi -

```
SET @total_characters =  CHAR_LENGTH(@name);
SELECT @total_characters;
+-------------------+
| @total_characters |
+-------------------+
|                14 |
+-------------------+
```

---

**Case 1:**

Now, in variable `@test` I store `@name` converted to `ucs2` character set -

```
SET @test = CONVERT(@name USING ucs2);
```

Now, in variable `@total_bytes` I store the length of `@test` in terms of bytes -

```
SET @total_bytes = LENGTH(@test);
SELECT @total_bytes;
+--------------+
| @total_bytes |
+--------------+
|           28 |
+--------------+
```

Now, `ucs2` character set allocated 2 bytes per character.

Thus, `2 * @total_characters = @total_bytes`

---

**Case 2:**

Now, in variable `@test` I store `@name` converted to `utf32` character set -

```
SET @test = CONVERT(@name USING utf32);
```

Now, in variable `@total_bytes` I store the length of `@test` in terms of bytes -

```
SET @total_bytes = LENGTH(@test);
SELECT @total_bytes;
+--------------+
| @total_bytes |
+--------------+
|           56 |
+--------------+
```

Now, `utf32` character set allocates 4 bytes per character.

Thus, `4 * @total_characters = @total_bytes`

---

To see all character sets supported by MySQL use -

```
SHOW CHARACTER SET;
```