# MySQL - How to select data by string length

Tags: mysql, select, string-length

```sql
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY string_length(column);
```

Is there a MySQL function to do this (of course instead of `string_length`)?

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734334/mysql-length-vs-char-length

Answer (score 574, accepted):

You are looking for [`CHAR_LENGTH()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length) to get the number of characters in a string.

For multi-byte charsets [`LENGTH()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_length) will give you the number of bytes the string occupies, while `CHAR_LENGTH()` will return the number of characters.

Comment: Actually, CHAR_LENGTH() should be a better choice. For multi-byte charsets LENGTH() will give you the number of bytes the string occupies, while CHAR_LENGTH() will return the number of characters.

Comment: It is correct to send an integer parameter to `CHAR_LENGTH`, since if I return the number of characters ? , por ejemplo `CHAR_LENGTH(12)` return `2`

Comment: @fubo in mySQL 8.0 ```select LENGTH('Ö');``` result is ```1```. same with ```CHAR_LENGTH()```, ```OCTET_LENGTH()```

Answer (score 101):

```
SELECT * FROM table 
ORDER BY LENGTH(column);
```

Documentation on the `LENGTH()` function, as well as all the other string functions, is available [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_length).

Answer (score 32):

Having a look at [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html) for the string functions, we can also use `CHAR_LENGTH()` and `CHARACTER_LENGTH()` as well.

Answer (score 21):

> In my case I get data using mobile number length greater than 10 digits using the below query

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(mobile) > 10;
```

Answer (score 5):

The function that I use to find the length of the string is `length`, used as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY length(column);
```

Answer (score 4):

I used this sentences to filter

```
SELECT table.field1, table.field2 FROM table WHERE length(field) > 10;
```

you can change 10 for other number that you want to filter.

Answer (score -2):

```
select * from *tablename* where 1 having length(*fieldname*)=*fieldlength*
```

Example if you want to select from customer the entry's with a name shorter then 2 chars.

```
select * from customer where 1 **having length(name)<2**
```