# How to select one text column, which string length >0?

Tags: mysql

Is there any function like "strlen" in mysql?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Mysql does have a [length](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_length) function to return the length of a string.

so you could do something like.

```
select * from some_table where length(some_string) > 0;
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with using `LENGTH` keyword

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE LENGTH (name) > 150;
```

Answer (score 4):

> How to select one text column, which string length >0 ?

You could compare to the empty string:

```
SELECT yourcolumn
FROM yourtable
WHERE yourcolumn <> ''
```

Answer (score 1):

The following query would do the job for you.

```
select length(your_text_column) from sample_table where length(some_column) > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who comes across this answer in Google, keep this in mind:

> Actually, CHAR_LENGTH() should be a better choice. For multi-byte charsets LENGTH() will give you the number of bytes the string occupies, while CHAR_LENGTH() will return the number of characters

[MySQL - How to select data by string length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1870937/mysql-how-to-select-data-by-string-length#comment9742744_1870942)