# querying WHERE condition to character length?

Tags: sql, conditional-statements, where-clause

I have a database with a large number of words but i want to select only those records where the character length is equal to a given number (in example case 3):

```
$query = ("SELECT * FROM $db WHERE conditions AND length = 3");
```

But this does not work... can someone show me the correct query?

Answer (score 195, accepted):

Sorry, I wasn't sure which SQL platform you're talking about:

In MySQL:

```
$query = ("SELECT * FROM $db WHERE conditions AND LENGTH(col_name) = 3");
```

in MSSQL

```
$query = ("SELECT * FROM $db WHERE conditions AND LEN(col_name) = 3");
```

The LENGTH() (MySQL) or LEN() (MSSQL) function will return the length of a string in a column that you can use as a condition in your WHERE clause.

**Edit**

I know this is really old but thought I'd expand my answer because, as Paulo Bueno rightly pointed out, you're most likely wanting the number of characters as opposed to the number of bytes. Thanks Paulo.

So, for MySQL there's the `CHAR_LENGTH()`. The following example highlights the difference between `LENGTH()` an `CHAR_LENGTH()`:

```
CREATE TABLE words (
    word VARCHAR(100)
) ENGINE INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO words(word) VALUES('快樂'), ('happy'), ('hayır');

SELECT word, LENGTH(word) as num_bytes, CHAR_LENGTH(word) AS num_characters FROM words;

+--------+-----------+----------------+
| word   | num_bytes | num_characters |
+--------+-----------+----------------+
| 快樂    |         6 |              2 |
| happy  |         5 |              5 |
| hayır  |         6 |              5 |
+--------+-----------+----------------+
```

Be careful if you're dealing with multi-byte characters.

Comment: The MySQL syntax is the same as the SQLite syntax. Worked great for me.

Comment: In postgres you can use "length" function like in mysql

Comment: Beware! In multi-byte charsets it may be different. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1870937/mysql-how-to-select-data-by-string-length)

Comment: In SQL Server (MS SQL), the LEN function will return number of characters but it will not count trailing spaces. So the solution might be to add non-space character at the end, and then subtract 1 from the result of LEN. Source (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/len-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks).

Answer (score 9):

I think you want this:

```
select *
from dbo.table
where DATALENGTH(column_name) = 3
```

Comment: DATALENGHT takes into account the additionaly bytes used by unicode characters

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT *
   FROM   my_table
   WHERE  substr(my_field,1,5) = "abcde";
```