# MySQL Not Equal To Certain Length

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a Phone_Numbers column. I want to delete all rows that do not have the exact length of 10 digits.

Comment: First, you have to write a query. Try that and then come back if you have questions about that. That is, no one is going to write a query for you, especially based on an unknown schema with unknown constraints and unknown requirements. See [ask].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [querying WHERE condition to character length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807231/querying-where-condition-to-character-length)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before asking a question you should try, and if you don't succeed please provide the code you wrote.

You can use the LENGHT fonction :

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE LENGTH(Phone_Numbers) != 10
```

Comment: Phone numbers are subject to all kind of formatting "rules" want happens if the string contains a `000-000-00` format is to still a valid phone number? @Rakonu think about that because this query does not handle those "rules"

Comment: You say that however you feed the answer anyway. Not the best way to make people stop asking for code don't you think ?

Comment: Note that the MySQL `LENGTH` function returns a number of *bytes*, the `CHAR_LENGTH` function returns number of *characters*. (Those will be the same for single byte characterset such as latin1, but is not necessarily true for a multibyte characterset (e.g. utf8). I also strongly recommend testing with a SELECT statement, as a verification, before turning it into a DELETE statement.