# SQL Select row where column has certain length and max value

Tags: mysql, sql

| Column_A | Column_B | Column_C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Value 1 | 111A001 | some value 1 |
| Value 1 | 111A002 | some value 2 |
| Value 2 | 112A001 | some value 3 |
| Value 2 | 112A002 | some value 4 |
| Value 2 | 112A003 | some value 5 |
| Value 2 | 112A004 | some value 6 |
| Value 3 | 115A001 | some value 7 |
| Value 3 | 115A002 | some value 8 |
| Value 3 | 115A003 | some value 9 |
| Value 4 | 117A | some value 10 |

Hallo everyone,

I have a question regarding SQL query.

From the table above, I want to get an output as below:

| Column_A | Column_B | Column_C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Value 1 | 111A002 | some value 2 |
| Value 2 | 112A004 | some value 6 |
| Value 3 | 115A003 | some value 9 |

Value 4 is not selected because in Column_B after 'A' there is nothing or it didn't have 3 digit. As you can see in the top table, value 1 has 2 value in column B, 111A001 and 111A002. I want to select 111A002. Value 2 has 4 value in column B, 112A001 - 112A004, I want to choose only 112A004. So the point is I want to select the highest value (in column_b) from each value in column_A.

I tried with max(column_B) but it only show Value 4, 117A, some value 10.

I apologize if the title is not correct.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [querying WHERE condition to character length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807231/querying-where-condition-to-character-length)

Comment: what's your database?

Comment: Hi @tgdavies, unfortunately, it is no.

Comment: Hi @JaimeDrq, it is mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this is what you are looking for:

```
select 
  Column_A,
  max(Column_B) as Column_B,
  max(Column_C) as Column_C
from d
where length(substring(Column_B,locate('A', Column_B) + 1)) >= 3
group by Column_A
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select column_a,
max(column_b),
max(column_c) /* Depends if you want max of column_c or column c value corresponding to the max of column_b - Question wasn't very clear */
from table
where column_b not like '%A___' /* Because you said - "Value 4 is not selected because in Column_B after 'A' there is nothing or it didn't have 3 digit." */
group by column_a
```

You can use this if you know for sure, there will always be 3 digits after "A" or ___A% if its 3 digits before "A" (which also might be right, going by the data you've posted)

`%A%` might not work for you, since it'll also consider strings ending with "A"; whereas you need something after "A"

Even better would be to use a function like `length(column_b) = 7` if you're sure that the string will have X characters.
Not sure which database you're on. So the function might be different. Some DBs have CHAR_LENGTH() or LEN()

Edit: Just clarifying that ___ is 3 underscores. Wanted to clarify because it just looks like one big line