# Sort by the number of words in a MySQL field

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I would like to sort a result from a MySQL query by the number of words in a specified column.

Something like this:

```
SELECT bar FROM foo ORDER BY WordCountFunction(bar)
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Check mysql LENGTH() ! 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1870937/mysql-how-to-select-data-by-string-length

Comment: In what language are these words written?

Comment: @Vucko the correct spelling is `LENGTH`. And this function will not return the number of words in a text.

Comment: Thanks, i missed it somehow. But what about LEN() ?
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_len.asp

Comment: `LEN()` just returns the length of a field, and not how many words are potentially included in it. From memory, I don't think it's even valid in MySQL either.

Comment: Official MySQL documentation: [String functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html). There is really no need to refer to W3schools website.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, there is no word count function in MySQL, but you can count the number of spaces and add one if your data is formatted properly (space separator for words, no spaces at beginning/end of entry).

Here is the query listing longest words first:

```
SELECT bar FROM foo ORDER BY (LENGTH(bar) - LENGTH(REPLACE(bar, ' ', ''))+1) DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, sort of. It won't be 100% accurate though:

```
SELECT SUM(LENGTH(bar) - LENGTH(REPLACE(bar, ' ', ''))+1) as count
FROM table
ORDER BY count DESC
```

But this assumes the words are separated by a space `' '` and doesn't account for punctuation. You can always replace it with another char and it doesn't account for double spaces or other chars either.

For complete accuracy, you could always pull the result out and word-count in your language of choice - where accurate word-count function do exist!

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'd agree that it's probably easier to do the word count in an external language- you could just use a tokenizer and trim properly. Replacing spaces seems like somewhat of a hack-ish solution.

Comment: @StevenLiao Yes, used as an approximation, this is a good technique, but not accurate 100% on written texts. Good if you've got many fields to scan over and return an approx result set.

Answer (score 2):

Using [this method](http://www.mwasif.com/2008/12/count-number-of-words-in-a-mysql-column/) to count the number of words in a column, your query would look like this:

`SELECT bar FROM foo ORDER BY (LENGTH(bar) - LENGTH(REPLACE(bar, ' ', ''))+1) DESC`