# Filter results by the column length

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to filter some results from a query where the field must have more than a given length.
I know that doesn't work, but it would be something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE COUNT(description) > 50
```

Is that doable or will I have to filter that on PHP(in my case) later?

Comment: `I know that doesn't work`<-- you should throw this thought out when you do something (at-least before asking at SO).

Comment: By the way, an aggregate function cannot be used in WHERE clause. You could probably use - 
select * from my_table
where length(my_col)>50;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given you're using MySQL, you're probably looking for `LENGTH()`.

For standard SQL, the function is called `LEN()`.

If you are dealing with UTF-8, you will have to use `CHAR_LENGTH()` as `LENGTH()` measures the length in bytes while `CHAR_LENGTH()` will correctly measure the length in characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE LENGTH(description) < 50
```

Comment: Amended LEN to LENGTH

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE LENGTH(description) > 50
```

Read more: [LENGTH](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_length) function in mysql.

Reference: [MySQL - How to select data by string length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1870937/mysql-how-to-select-data-by-string-length)

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE LENGTH(description) > 50
```