# max(length(field)) in mysql

Tags: sql, mysql

If I say:

```
select max(length(Name)) 
  from my_table
```

I get the result as 18, but I want the concerned data also.  So if I say:

```
select max(length(Name)), 
       Name 
  from my_table
```

...it does not work. There should be a self join I guess which I am unable to figure it out.

Can anyone please provide me a clue?

Comment: I would recommend that you consider using CHAR_LENGTH() instead of LENGTH(). CHAR_LENGTH() returns the length of a string in characters. LENGTH() returns its length in bytes. For multi-byte character sets these values can be different, and you are probably concerned with character length, not byte length.

Answer (score 191):

```
SELECT  name, LENGTH(name) AS mlen
FROM    mytable
ORDER BY
        mlen DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 17):

Edited, will work for unknown max() values:

```
select name, length( name )
from my_table
where length( name ) = ( select max( length( name ) ) from my_table );
```

Comment: yes, but i want the concerned `name` which has maxlenght of 18

Comment: ok I managed to get what I want like this `select max(length(Name)) as num1,Name from my_table group by Name having num1 = 18`, since I know from the first query that max is 18. But how to combine this to one query?

Comment: Ah, okay, I misread that.  In MS SQL I would use select Name from my_table where length(Name) = (select max(length(Name)) from my_table), but I am fairly certain that is not correct MySQL syntax.

Answer (score 9):

Ok, I am not sure what are you using(MySQL, SLQ Server, Oracle, MS Access..)
But you can try the code below. It work in W3School example DB. [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_like) 
try this:

```
SELECT city, max(length(city)) FROM Customers;
```

Comment: with mysql; "this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by"

Answer (score 6):

In case you need both max and min from same table:

```
    select * from (
(select city, length(city) as maxlen from station
order by maxlen desc limit 1)
union
(select city, length(city) as minlen from station
order by minlen,city limit 1))a;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
  SELECT mt.name 
    FROM MY_TABLE mt
GROUP BY mt.name
  HAVING MAX(LENGTH(mt.name)) = 18
```

...assuming you know the length beforehand.  If you don't, use:

```
  SELECT mt.name 
    FROM MY_TABLE mt
    JOIN (SELECT MAX(LENGTH(x.name) AS max_length
            FROM MY_TABLE x) y ON y.max_length = LENGTH(mt.name)
```

Comment: @JPro: Check the explain plan, but I think Quassnoi's is likely the most optimal.

Answer (score 2):

```
Select URColumnName From URTableName Where length(URColumnName ) IN 
(Select max(length(URColumnName)) From URTableName);
```

This will give you the records in that particular column which has the maximum length.

Answer (score 2):

Use CHAR_LENGTH() instead-of LENGTH() as suggested in: 
[MySQL - length() vs char_length()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734334/mysql-length-vs-char-length)

SELECT name, CHAR_LENGTH(name) AS mlen
FROM mytable
ORDER BY mlen DESC
LIMIT 1

Comment: in my case, I want to know if datas in mediumtext could be copied in tinytext field so `length` is what I need !

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from my_table 
where length( Name ) = ( 
      select max( length( Name ) ) 
      from my_table
      limit 1 
);
```

It this involves two table scans, and so might not be very fast !

Comment: The limit in the sub-query is unnecessary:  max() is an aggregation operator and will only return 1 row.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could use a solution such as this one :

```
select name, length(name)
from users
where id = (
    select id
    from users
    order by length(name) desc
    limit 1
);
```

Might not be the optimal solution, though... But seems to work.