# How do I get the highest numbers of characters of varchar values stored in columns in a table in MySQL ?

Tags: mysql

I have a table named "**cities**" which have thousands of records with only two fields namely  ***city*** and ***state***. Though the type and length of the both fields defined as varchar(100) in my table, I am sure no values in  the columns took up 100 characters. I want to write a query to know which value of the ***state*** ***column*** takes the heighest numbers of characters. I tried with:

```
select distinct max(state) from cities;
```

I know this is not the query what I want. Is there any SQL function to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don’t need `distinct`; there is only one maximum length.

To return the state(s) with the longest value:

```
select state
from cities
where length(state) = (select max(length(state)) from cities)
```

——-

These queries might be more helpful...

To return all states and their length, whose length is longer than a certain length (eg 10):

```
select state, length(state)
from cities
where length(state) > 10
order by 2 desc
```

To return the longest 10 state names and their length:

```
select state, length(state)
from cities
order by 2 desc
limit 10
```

Comment: Sir, in all your queries above, what does 2 actually mean in "order by 2" phrase?

Comment: The third query doesn't quite do that , but I admit we're splitting hairs

Comment: Also, you're assuming (not unreasonably) that state names are composed of non-multibyte characters.

Comment: @rosemary `order by 2` means *order by selected column number 2*. It’s standard SQL, so it’s portable, and is simpler especially when the column is an expression, which you then don’t have to maintain in both the select and order by clauses.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use `ORDER BY` with `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT state, CHAR_LENGTH(state) AS length
FROM cities
ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(state) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

If there could be ties and you also want those ties, then we can try a different approach.

Answer (score -1):

This question is *Duplicate* But i will answer, you should use `length()` function with the `max()` function which i got [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2357620/maxlengthfield-in-mysql) :-

```
select max(length(state)) from cities;
```

Comment: You would never use DISTINCT and MAX together in this fashion