# mysql period(.) search pattern

Tags: mysql, regex

I need a scenario where results need to be sorted out depending on the number of periods in it.

Field values are:

```
aa.bb.ee.tt
aa.tt.ee
aa.tt
```

If I want to search only values which consist on a single period, what will be the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if column name is ***str***, and you put **substr = "."** in the following SQL, you will get what you want. Sorted by number of periods in the column str

```
SELECT (LENGTH(str) - LENGTH(REPLACE(str, substr, ''))) / LENGTH(substr) AS cnt
...
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

Comment: @Nishant I guess OP asked for a mysql query with order by, and regex was just his guess for the right answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I asked about the MySQL  query.

Comment: @HarpreetS this will have a problem if the string is encoded in `UTF-8`. see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734334/mysql-length-vs-char-length

Comment: Fields are only in number or in English alphabets., So I don't think It'll be a problem

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no inbuilt MySQL function to count the occurrence of a character in string, we can do it by using these steps:

1. Counting the number of characters in the original string
2. Temporarily ‘deleting’ the character you want to count and count the string again
3. Subtract the first count from the second to get the number of occurrences

Ex.

```
SELECT CHAR_LENGTH('hello') - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE('hello', 'l', '')) AS `COUNT`
```

returns 2

and if you want to order the results,

```
SELECT CHAR_LENGTH(colName) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(colName, xChar, '')) AS `COUNT`
FROM tableName
ORDER BY `COUNT` DESC
```

WHERE

`colName` is the name of the column that contains your string 
`xChar` is the character you want to find

BTW, use `CHAR_LENGTH()` instead of `LENGTH()` because `LENGTH()` returns the length of the string **measured in bytes**. `CHAR_LENGTH()` returns the length of the string **measured in characters**.

Comment: This solution worked fine for me. I put count in where clause. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void CheckPeriod(string stringLine)  
{  
int counter = 0;

foreach (char c in stringLine)  
{  
if(c == ".")  
{  
counter = counter + 1;  
}    
}  

if(counter == 1)  
{  
//Do code  
}  
}
```

Hope this helps, or points in the right direction

Comment: I think he means for a SQL query that returns results based on how many dots the given column has.

Comment: It was easy doing in programming. But I need it at database end.

Answer (score 0):

hmm you could something like

```
 SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE COL_NAME REGEXP "[A-Za-z0-9]*\.[A-Za-z0-9]*"
```

for getting single period values and add more periods same way for more than one period results