# How can I select the longest text field when using GROUP BY in mysql, a la MAX()?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

In MySql you can use the `MAX()` function to get the highest value when using `GROUP BY`, how can I do the same thing to get the longest string of text?

Sample table:

```
id_|_post_id|_title__________|_body_____________________________________________
1  | ZXBF1J | Favorite Color | My favorite color is blue.
2  | ZXBF1J | Favorite Color | My favorite color is blue, no wait...
3  | ZXBF1J | Favorite Color | My favorite color is blue, no wait, yelloooow!
4  | AR3D47 | Quest          | To seek..
5  | AR3D47 | Quest          | To seek the Holy
6  | AR3D47 | Quest          | To seek the Holy Grail.
```

The tricky part is that I want to `ORDER BY id ASC` to see the oldest entries on the top, and I want to group by the `post_id` which is not something that I can use to `ORDER`, and get the longest `body`.

Sample query:

```
SELECT post_id, title, MAX(body) // obviously MAX() doesn't work here
FROM posts
GROUP BY post_id
ORDER BY id ASC
```

Desired output:

```
post_id|_title__________|_body_____________________________________________
ZXBF1J | Favorite Color | My favorite color is blue, no wait, yelloooow!
AR3D47 | Quest          | To seek the Holy Grail.
```

Again the key is to select the longest `body` while maintaining the order based on the `id`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need use `CHAR_LENGTH` instead of `LENGTH`

```
SELECT a.id, a.post_id, a.body
FROM posts a INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT post_ID, title, MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(body)) totalLength
    FROM posts
    GROUP BY post_ID, title
) b ON a.post_id = b.post_ID AND
        a.title = b.title AND
        CHAR_LENGTH(a.body) = b.totalLength
```

You might want to see the difference: **[CHAR_LENGTH( ) vs LENGTH( )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734334/mysql-length-vs-char-length)**

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d146d/2)

Comment: I guess you win since your CHAR_LENGTH seems to be better for non latin charsets

Answer (score 5):

```
select p.post_id, p.title, p.body
from posts p
inner join (
  select post_id, max(length(body)) as MaxLength
  from posts
  group by post_id
) pm on p.post_id = pm.post_id and length(p.body) = MaxLength
order by p.id
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/82e8a/7)

Comment: SQL Fiddle - nice. did not know about that one.