# Selecting the longest string in each field

Tags: sql-server, aggregate-functions

I am trying to clean up a data set similar in structure to the following table:

```
dataSource

| ID_dec | ID_base | name | field1        | field2       | field3       |
| 1.01   | 1       | AAA  | Cat           | Brown        | Domesticated |
| 1.02   | 1       | AAA  | Cat           | Brown        | Domesticated |
| 1.03   | 1       | AAA  | Feline        | NULL         | Dom.         |
| 1.04   | 1       | AAA  | Beautiful cat | NULL         | NULL         |
| 1.05   | 1       | AAA  | NULL          | Light Brown  | NULL         |
| 2.01   | 2       | BBB  | Dog           | Black        | Wild         |
| 2.02   | 2       | BBB  | Barker        | NULL         | NULL         |
| 3.01   | 3       | CCC  | Bird          | Yellow       | Domesticated |
| 4.01   | 4       | DDD  | Snake         | NULL         | NULL         |
| 4.02   | 4       | DDD  | NULL          | Green        | NULL         |
| 4.03   | 4       | DDD  | NULL          | Forest Green | NULL         |
| 4.04   | 4       | DDD  | NULL          | Green        | Wild         |
| 4.05   | 4       | DDD  | NULL          | NULL         | Wild         |
```

I want to pull the longest string of each combination of `field[N]` and `ID_base`, like so:

```
result

| ID_base | name | field1        | field2       | field3       |
| 1       | AAA  | Beautiful cat | Light Brown  | Domesticated |
| 2       | BBB  | Barker        | Black        | Wild         |
| 3       | CCC  | Bird          | Yellow       | Domesticated |
| 4       | DDD  | Snake         | Forest Green | Wild         |
```

[This has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12250514/how-can-i-select-the-longest-text-field-when-using-group-by-in-mysql-a-la-max), but only while examining to a single field. The following SQL gets me the desired result, but feels inefficient when scaled up to the real data set of 37 fields and 5665 rows (4029 `ID_base`s and the most `ID_dec`s to a single `ID_base` is 10):

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id_base, a.name, b.result, c.result, d.result
FROM
    dataSource a
    LEFT JOIN
        (
        SELECT y.id_base, max(y.field1) result
        FROM dataSource y
        LEFT JOIN
            (
            SELECT id_base, max(len(field1)) leng
            FROM dataSource
            GROUP BY id_base
            ) z
            ON y.id_base = z.id_base
        WHERE len(y.field1) = z.leng
        GROUP BY y.id_base
        ) b
    ON a.id_base = b.id_base
    LEFT JOIN
        (
        SELECT y.id_base, max(y.field2) result
        FROM dataSource y
        LEFT JOIN
            (
            SELECT id_base, max(len(field2)) leng
            FROM dataSource
            GROUP BY id_base
            ) z
            ON y.id_base = z.id_base
        WHERE len(y.field1) = z.leng
        GROUP BY y.id_base
        ) c
    ON a.id_base = c.id_base
    LEFT JOIN
        (
        SELECT y.id_base, max(y.field3) result
        FROM dataSource y
        LEFT JOIN
            (
            SELECT id_base, max(len(field3)) leng
            FROM dataSource
            GROUP BY id_base
            ) z
            ON y.id_base = z.id_base
        WHERE len(y.field1) = z.leng
        GROUP BY y.id_base
        ) d
    ON a.id_base = d.id_base
```

What is the best way to go about this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH a AS (
    SELECT id_base, name, max(len(field1)) l1, max(len(field2)) l2, max(len(field3)) l3 
    FROM datasource
    GROUP BY id_base, name
)
SELECT a.*,
  (SELECT TOP 1 field1 FROM datasource WHERE id_base = a.id_base AND len(field1) = a.l1),
  (SELECT TOP 1 field2 FROM datasource WHERE id_base = a.id_base AND len(field2) = a.l2),
  (SELECT TOP 1 field3 FROM datasource WHERE id_base = a.id_base AND len(field3) = a.l3)
from a
```

Answer (score 1):

Another simpler variation:

```
SELECT 
      t.id_base, 
      t.name 
      (SELECT TOP 1 field1 FROM table WHERE id_base = t.id_base ORDER BY LEN(field1) DESC),
      (SELECT TOP 1 field2 FROM table WHERE id_base = t.id_base ORDER BY LEN(field2) DESC),
      (SELECT TOP 1 field3 FROM table WHERE id_base = t.id_base ORDER BY LEN(field3) DESC)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT id_base, name FROM table) t
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select coalesce(t1.ID_base, t2.ID_base, t3.ID_base) base,
   coalesce(t1.Name, t2.Name, t3.Name) Name,
   coalesce(t1.field1, t2.field1, t3.field1) field1,
   coalesce(t1.field2, t2.field2, t3.field2) field2,
   coalesce(t1.field3, t2.field3, t3.field3) field3
from dataSource t1
   full join dataSource t2 on t2.ID_base = t1.ID_base 
       and len(t1.field1) = (Select Max(len(field1)) from dataSource 
                             where ID_base = t1.ID_base)
       and len(t2.field2) = (Select Max(len(field2)) from dataSource 
                             where ID_base = t2.ID_base)
   full join dataSource t3 on t3.ID_base = t1.ID_base 
       and len(t3.field3) = (Select Max(len(field3)) from dataSource 
                             where ID_base = t3.ID_base)
```