# Select rows with a duplicate field based on another field

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I'm trying without success to solve this tricky point.
I have a mysql table like the following:

```
Category      Model      Description
cat1           AAA       Triple A
cat1/cat2      AAA       Triple A
cat1/cat2      BBB       Triple B
cat1           BBB       Triple B
cat3           CCC       Triple C
cat3/cat4/cat5 CCC       Triple C
cat3/cat4      CCC       Triple C
```

etc.

I would like to select rows with unique Model and "longest" Category. Basically I would like to obtain:

```
Category      Model      Description
cat1/cat2      AAA       Triple A
cat1/cat2      BBB       Triple B
cat3/cat4/cat5 CCC       Triple C
```

Any hint?

Comment: If at all possible, you ought to split `Category` out into another table that links each category to a `Model`  in a one-to-many relationship.  You would then avoid this problem entirely.

Comment: I understand your point. Actually I have a situation similar to that one you are describing. But I need also the information of the deepest category path.

Comment: I see - I assumed that rather than paths, those were delimited category lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select m.*
from MyTable m
inner join (
    select Model, max(char_length(Category)) as MaxLen
    from MyTable
    group by Model
) mm on m.Model = mm.Model and char_length(m.Category) = mm.MaxLen
```

You may in fact, want the deepest category rather than longest. If this is the case, there are better options than above.

Comment: +1 How about a `DISTINCT` to dedupe those where there are multiple rows for a Category length, which if I'm not mistaken, would return in your outer `select m.*`?

Comment: you should change `len()` to `length()` for mysql

Comment: One more thing, I'd rather use `CHAR_LENGTH`instead of `LENGTH`. [Click here for better explanation by Andomar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734334/mysql-length-vs-char-length)

Comment: Great, it worked perfectly... maybe this is the answer on the Gordon Linoff solution.

Comment: Sorry my comment is not clear maybe... I was just saying: maybe this is the answer to my question in Gordon Linoff solution.

Comment: @madimar See my comment on Gordons's solution.

Answer (score 3):

From the data that you provide, the following will work:

```
select max(category), Model, Description
from t
group by Model, Description
```

This is because "cat1" < "cat1/cat2" and so on.

Comment: +1 I wouldn't have thought of that. And based on the liberal requirement of "the longest string", it doesn't particularly matter if there are two equal length strings that contain different categories. `MAX()` will just pull the greater by string comparison.

Comment: Hmm, it seems a simple solution, I just have a minimal concern. Actually my real table has a lot of fields. Is there a way to select all of them?

Comment: Not the most robust solution—add a category named `z` and see what happens. This is basically the same as `ORDER BY category DESC LIMIT 1`.

Answer (score 1):

If "longuest" means the maximum number of `/` in Category (as it should be), try this :

```
SELECT
    t.Category
    , t.Model
    , t.Description
FROM
    t
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            Model
            , MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(Category) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(Category, '/', ''))) AS Depth
        FROM
            t
        GROUP BY
            Model
    ) AS tmax
        ON t.Model = tmax.Model
        AND CHAR_LENGTH(t.Category) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(t.Category, '/', '')) = tmax.Depth
```

Additionally, it seems to work : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/725e5/3/0