# mySQL length of all columns

Tags: mysql, multiple-columns

I have often SQL statements of the kind

```
SELECT LENGTH(col_name) FROM `table` WHERE *condition*
```

to establish the size of the contents of a specific column in a given row of a mySQL table.  However, it is not clear to me that there is a single SQL statement that would fetch the sum of the content lengths of ALL the columns in a given row.  I should add that all the columns in question are VARCHARS.

Yes, I know I could do this by fetching the entire row as

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE *condition*
```

collapsing the resulting row contents into a string and getting the length of that string but I was wondering if there isn't a more efficient one liner to do the job.  Any tips would be much appreciated.

Comment: can you give specific example?

Comment: Well, it is quite simple actually.  For example, I have a table in which I store information that gets showed in an HTML "news ticker".  The table has four columns - ticker "story" text, ticker story author and ticker story location and finally a ticker story id.  From time to time I have clean up code that discards an old story by its id. When I do I need to get the lengths of the story text, story author and story location fields for that id.  I can do that but all in a single SQL statement via LENGTH or the like would be nice.

Comment: is this what you want? `SELECT CHAR_LENGTH(CONCAT(col1,col2,col3)) FROM tableName WHERE...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I prefer to use [`CHAR_LENGTH` over `LENGTH`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734334/mysql-length-vs-char-length)

```
SELECT CHAR_LENGTH(CONCAT(col1,col2,col3)) 
FROM tableName 
WHERE...
```

From the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734334/)

> LENGTH() returns the length of the string measured in bytes.
>
> CHAR_LENGTH() returns the length of the string measured in characters.

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks a lot.  CHAR_LEGNTH vs LENGTH is irrelevant in my case since all my data are base64 encoded.

Comment: Problem: If one of the columns is NULL, than CONCAT is NULL, than CHAR_LENGTH of these columns is NULL, even one of the columns has a value.

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution without going into column names:

```
SELECT SUM(character_maximum_length) length,
  table_name
  FROM information_schema.columns 
  WHERE table_name='your_table_name_here'
  AND table_schema=DATABASE()
  -- AND column_name IN ('choose', 'columns')
  GROUP BY table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

SELECT char_length(col_name)+char_length(col_name2) FROM `table` WHERE *condition*

Comment: Thanks, that would work too but the version with CONCAT is more elegant. Pity CONCAT does not accept * though :-/