# String length limit to minimum characters with MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to select some subjects from db.. I used below code to select coma separated list of subjects.

```
GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT s.subject_name SEPARATOR ', ') AS subjects,
```

its ok. its working for me. Its output is something like this.

> Mathematics, Physiology, Business & Accounting Studies, Catholicism

Now I need to limit this string to 35 characters and need to add '...' at the end of the string.

It is something like this.

```
Mathematics, Physiology, Business...
```

So, can I know is it possible along with mysql when select the query?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this,

```
SELECT  IF(CHAR_LENGTH(subjects) > 35, CONCAT(LEFT(subjects,35), '...'), subjects),
        ...
FROM
(
    SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT s.subject_name SEPARATOR ', ') AS subjects,
            ...
    FROM    tableName
    GROUP   BY ...
) s
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/7218)

I'd rather use `CHAR_LENGTH` than `LENGTH` when getting length of the character because...

- [CHAR_LENGTH vs LENGTH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734334/mysql-length-vs-char-length)

Comment: My real query is very complex one for me.. It has created with more tables data...

Comment: check this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824791/how-do-i-modify-this-select-query-in-mysql

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `CASE` expression that will check the [`LENGTH()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_length) of the `subjects`. If it is longer than 35 characters then you can apply [`SUBSTRING()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) and `CONCAT()` to get the new value with the `...` at the end:

```
select  
   case 
     when length(subjects) > 35
     then concat(substr(subjects, 1, 35), '...')
     else subjects end as subjects
from
(
  select GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT subject_name SEPARATOR ', ') AS subjects
  from yourtable
) src
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2c50/6).

This returns:

```
|                               SUBJECTS |
------------------------------------------
| Mathematics, Physiology, Business &... |
```

Comment: Thanks.. but problem with it when using in my real query.

Comment: @TharangaNuwan what is the problem?

Comment: @TharangaNuwan then you should edit your OP with more details on the problem including your full query and explain why these solutions do not work.

Answer (score 0):

just substring/concat it to the end of the result of group_concat

```
concat(substring(group_concat(distinct s.subject_name SEPARATOR ', '), 35), '...') AS subjects,
```

Usually it would be easier though, to do this in the application when using frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Store your result in a variable and in an if clause check whether it is longer than 32 characters. If so select its first 32 characters and concatenate '...' to it.