# mysql Length() for different languages returns different size

Tags: mysql

```
select 

length('abcdefg') english,
length('가나다라마바사') korean

from dual
```

This returns below.

```
english korean
7       21
```

Is there any function returning the count of character not character bytes?

I mean what I need is

```
english korean
7       7
```

Comment: Take a look to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734334/mysql-length-vs-char-length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [the manual:](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_length)

> Returns the length of the string str, measured in bytes. A multi-byte character counts as multiple bytes. This means that for a string containing five 2-byte characters, LENGTH() returns 10, whereas [CHAR_LENGTH()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length) returns 5.

[`CHAR_LENGTH()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length) will do what you want.

Answer (score 3):

use :

> CHAR_LENGTH()

(the number of characters)

reference :

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length