# SHORTEST and LONGEST string ORDERED alphabetically in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table structure like this:

```
      table users
+-------+--------------+
| Field |     Type     |
+-------+--------------+
|   id  |      INT     |
+-------+--------------+
|  name | VARCHAR(255) |
+-------+--------------+
```

I want to a single query that should return the longest and smallest NAME as well as their respective lengths when ordered alphabetically.

For e.g.

Suppose the data is (it's dummy)

```
ABA, BBA, PQR, HITS, QUES, PQRST, ABCDE
```

I want the query to return

```
+-------+---+
|  ABA  | 3 |
+-------+---+
| ABCDE | 5 |
+-------+---+
```

I tried:

```
(
SELECT minName, LENGTH(minName)
FROM (
    SELECT name AS minName 
    FROM users
    WHERE LENGTH(name)=(SELECT MIN(LENGTH(name)) FROM users)
    ) AS maxUsers
ORDER BY minName ASC
LIMIT 1
)
UNION
(
SELECT minName, LENGTH(minName)
FROM (
    SELECT name AS minName 
    FROM users
    WHERE LENGTH(name)=(SELECT MAX(LENGTH(name)) FROM users)
    ) AS maxUsers
ORDER BY minName ASC
LIMIT 1
)
```

How can I make this query short? Any one?

Comment: "You can't scare me. I'm sticking with the `UNION`."  From an old song.

Comment: Which database are you using.  Please do not tag every database you can think of?

Comment: @O.Jones haha! Woody Guthrie. I did that also but can't we make the query short?

Comment: @JonathanWillcock done!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simpler query that returns *all* the names with the minimum and maximum length:

```
SELECT u.Name, LENGTH(u.Name) as len
FROM users u JOIN
     (SELECT MIN(LENGTH(Name)) as minl, MAX(LENGTH(Name)) as maxl
      FROM users u
     ) uu
     ON LENGTH(u.name) IN (uu.minl, uu.maxl)
ORDER BY u.Name;
```

You want one of each length.  You can get this using an additional aggregation:

```
SELECT MIN(u.Name) as Name, LENGTH(u.Name) as len
FROM users u JOIN
     (SELECT MIN(LENGTH(Name)) as minl, MAX(LENGTH(Name)) as maxl
      FROM users u
     ) uu
     ON LENGTH(u.name) IN (uu.minl, uu.maxl)
GROUP BY LENGTH(u.Name)
ORDER BY MIN(name);
```

Comment: where is ordered alfabetically?

Comment: @IamMashed . . . I added explicit `ORDER BY`s into the answer.  I must've missed that requirement when I first read the question.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use UNION try this

```
(
    SELECT 
       name,
       LENGTH(name)
    FROM users
    ORDER BY LENGTH(name), name ASC
    LIMIT 1
)
UNION
(
    SELECT 
       name,
       LENGTH(name)
    FROM users
    ORDER BY LENGTH(name) DESC, name ASC
    LIMIT 1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Many solutions provide a solution which consists of multiple sub-queries which leads to a lot of confusion for SQL beginners. Here's a less complicated solution-

```
SELECT * FROM (
                  SELECT <COL_NAME>,LENGTH(<COL_NAME>) AS Length FROM <TABLE_NAME> 
                  ORDER BY 2,1 LIMIT 1
                  ) as MINIMUM 

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT * FROM (
                   SELECT <COL_NAME>,LENGTH(<COL_NAME>) AS Length FROM <TABLE_NAME> 
                   ORDER BY 2 DESC,1 LIMIT 1
                  ) as MAXIMUM;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use `CHAR_LENGTH` instead of `LENGTH`, otherwise you will get wrong results depending on the character set you are currently using.
Please have a look at [MySQL - length() vs char_length()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734334/mysql-length-vs-char-length)
`LENGTH()` returns the length of the string measured in bytes.
`CHAR_LENGTH()` returns the length of the string measured in characters.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

Try this: simpler and easier~

For the shortest

`SELECT MIN(name), LENGTH(MIN(name)) FROM users WHERE LENGTH(name)=(SELECT MIN(LENGTH(name)) FROM users);`

For the longest

`SELECT MAX(name), LENGTH(MAX(name)) FROM users WHERE LENGTH(name)=(SELECT MAX(LENGTH(name)) FROM users);`