# Insert same number, the result is different

Tags: mysql

this is my sql;

```
CREATE TABLE `a20171118sign` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT '姓名',
   `mobile` varchar(13) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '手机',
   `status` varchar(1) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '状态，0为未签到，1为已签到',
   `ip` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'IP地址',
   `date` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '签到时间'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `a20171118sign1` 
  (`id`, `name`, `mobile`, `status`, `ip`, `date`) 
VALUES
  (1, 'test1', '18995181962', '0', NULL, NULL),
  (2, 'test2', '18908178884', '0', NULL, NULL),
  (3, 'test3', '‭13805716757‬', '0', NULL, NULL);

SELECT LENGTH(mobile) FROM a20171118sign1;
```

Ok, there is something is interesting. The results are following

```
11
11
17
```

What happened to my data?
ps:I used `trim()` to test if there are some space, but it is not.

Comment: your database tables are different.

Comment: a20171118sign*1* and a20171118sign

Comment: You can check online sql fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/017aaf/1

Comment: yes and as you can see the last phone number is 17 length and not 11. I think it's is question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734334/mysql-length-vs-char-length

Comment: even with   CHAR_LENGTH(mobile) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3de822/4/0

Answer (score 1):

It seems to you have some invisible char at the start/end of  ‭13805716757‬
(unicode E280AD)

you can see it with this code :

```
HEX(LEFT(mobile, 1))
```

look here (the correct values) :  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/38339d/1
or here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/017aaf/8

Comment: yes but it's strange that the trim doesn't trim it, no ?

Comment: @DanielE. trim does only takes care of space character. so no, it make sense