# SQL search varchar with length in a range

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I want to search if names have a particular character length. Create a query that searches for names for e.g. between 5 characters and 10 characters. I am guessing its probably something to do with regex, but really got lost.

I want something like this

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE names characters > 5 AND names characters < 10"
```

How is this achieved?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_length

Comment: @Source, Can I help you further with this question?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to specifically find `character length` (string length measured in characters), you can use:

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(names) > 5 AND CHAR_LENGTH(names) < 10"
```

[Read here - length vs char_length](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1734340/3677457)

Answer (score 0):

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE LENGTH(names) BETWEEN 5 AND 10"
```

Comment: any major difference between char_len or length?

Comment: @Source - yes, see my answer and link below

Comment: @Source - `SELECT LENGTH('新浪新闻'), CHAR_LENGTH('新浪新闻');` --> 12 (bytes) and 4 (characters).

Answer (score 0):

Following code will be helpful for you,

```
SELECT members.*, 
LENGTH(names) AS ln 
FROM members 
HAVING ln 
BETWEEN 5 AND 10 ;
```

Comment: Why do you need post-aggregation filtering without any aggregation?

Comment: I don't see any "aggregation".  However, `WHERE` would work in place of `HAVING` except for the need to spell out `LENGTH(names)` instead of using the alias (`ln`).