# Selecting specific words within a table with a certain amount of characters

Tags: mysql, command-prompt

I am having trouble searching my table to find words that have an exact amount of characters.

I am trying to find specific movie titles within a film list with 8 characters and have tried using the 'like' part of the syntax but just end up getting error messages or the full film list. I am a little new with mysql so trying to get a foundation.

I know it is probably off but I am trying:

```
select title from film_list where varchar = '8';
```

I figured you can't use a data type in the where sequence but I am not sure where I am supposed to include it.

I have also tried:

```
select title from film_list where title like '8';
```

If you can point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: **Recommended reading:** https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`char_length()` returns the number of characters in a string. So you might want to use:

```
SELECT title
       FROM film_list
       WHERE char_length(title) = 8;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
select title from film_list where CHAR_LENGTH(title) = 8;
```

A useful reading on length and char_length is here:
[MySQL - length() vs char_length()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734334/mysql-length-vs-char-length)