# MySQL Query to delete entries containing words longer then 10 characters

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to search in Wp post(title) column and delete entries which contains words longer then 10 characters but i am unable to find a query to do that. can anyone help?
Edit: I made following SP.

```
    DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `p`(IN `instring` VARCHAR(255))
begin
declare   tempstring varchar(10000);
declare   idin int;
declare   outstring  varchar(100);
declare   c1 varchar(100);
declare   c2 varchar(100);
declare totallength int DEFAULT 0;
declare  checkit int;
declare done int;
DECLARE CUR1 CURSOR for SELECT id,post_title  FROM wp_posts;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
drop table if exists occursresults;
create table occursresults (col1 varchar(20), col2 varchar(20),totallength int );
open CUR1;
read_loop: LOOP
       FETCH CUR1  INTO idin,tempstring;
        if done then leave read_loop; end if;
        set checkit = 0;
        looper: while   tempstring is not null and instr(tempstring,' ') > 0 do
                set checkit = checkit + 1;
                if checkit > 100 then #In case of infinite loop
                    leave looper;
                end if;
                set outstring = substr(tempstring,1,instr(tempstring, ' ') - 1);
                set tempstring = ltrim(rtrim(replace(tempstring,concat(outstring,' '),'')));
                set c1 = substr(outstring,1,instr(outstring, ' ') - 1);
                set c2 = replace(outstring,concat(c1,' '),'');
                if Length(c2) > 10 then
               delete from wp_posts where id=idin;
                end if;
if Length(c2) < 10 then
                 INSERT INTO occursresults (COL1,COL2,totallength) VALUES (c1,c2,Length(c2));
                end if; 
                
                
        end while;
        select tempstring;
        set outstring = tempstring; 
        set c1 = substr(outstring,1,instr(outstring, ' ') - 1);
        set c2 = replace(outstring,concat(c1,' '),'');
       if Length(c2) > 10 then
               delete from wp_posts where id=idin;
                end if;
if Length(c2) < 10 then
                 INSERT INTO occursresults (COL1,COL2,totallength) VALUES (c1,c2,Length(c2));
                end if; 
end loop;
close cur1;

end$$
DELIMITER ;
```

but when i call it. i get this error.

Error
Static analysis:

1 errors were found during analysis.

Missing expression. (near "ON" at position 25)
SQL query: Edit Edit

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = ON;

MySQL said: Documentation

## 2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Comment: Look at regular expressions

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex to identify the rows to delete:

```
DELETE FROM post 
WHERE title RLIKE '[a-zA-Z]{10}'
```

This defines a word as a sequence of alphabetic characters. You might want to adapt the regex to add more characters if needed (digits, underscore, dash, ...).

Answer (score 0):

you can use `CHAR_LENGTH` as a function to get the length.

**Select:**

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    post
WHERE
    CHAR_LENGTH(title) > 10;
```

**Delete query:**

```
DELETE FROM post 
WHERE
    CHAR_LENGTH(title) > 10;
```

Note: `LENGTH` function too works but it will calculate in `bytes` rather than `chars`  more info on this refer this [MySQL - length() vs char_length()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734334/mysql-length-vs-char-length)

Comment: it returns all the rows. because i just need those title who contains words more then 10characters. but this query returns all the titles containing more then 10 char.( no the words)

Comment: i need only those titles which containt word length more then 10 characters.

Comment: what are you trying to say? you need to delete the rows which title column has more than 10 chars or need to just replace/ make `null` if it has more than 10 chars?

Comment: if title contains any word more then 10 characters, then delete that row. thats what i am saying. not the whole title. as title can contain any length, but not the single word.

Comment: Can you add some sample data in your question and expected result set.

Comment: sample: This is title no.1 and i dont contain any word longer then 10 chars.  <-------- this title is ok.

Comment: sample: This is title no.2 and i have word modifications causing single word having more then 10 char. <------ this tilte should be deleted by query

Comment: your sample is not clear, Need the sample based on sql tabular format with columns. Just edit your question and re-post.

Comment: added more details.